# joomla not showing full map of user group php

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

So I have made some custom user groups in Joomla from backend.
I put the registered users under these custom groups.
Groups are like this-

Public
|—  Users
|—|—    Auditor
|—|—    Custom_group1
|—|—|—  Custom_group2
|—|—|—|—    Custom_group3
|—|—|—|—|—  Administrator
|—|—|—|—|—|—    Super User
|—|—    Custom_group4

So, say that `user_b` is under group `Custom_group4` and also under `Custom_group3`,where the ids of custom group 3 and 4 are 2 and 11 respectively(say),
The MySql database would look like-

**Table: #__users**

```
id       name           username           email               password     
523     User A          user_a          user_a@mysite.com      blablabla...
524     User B          user_b          user_b@mysite.com      blablabla...
```

**Table: #__user_usergroup_map**

```
user_id(Foreign Key to #__users.id)       group_id(Foreign Key to #__usergroups.id)
    523                                       8
    524                                       2
    524                                       11
```

You can see there are two groups assigned for user id 524. 
Now I have this PHP code to get the group id for user(user id-524)

```
        $user = JFactory::getUser();
        $userId = $user->id;
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $recursive = False;

        // Build the database query to get the rules for the asset.
        $query  = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select('ug.group_id');
        $query->from('#__user_usergroup_map AS ug');
        $query->leftJoin('#__users AS a ON a.id = ug.user_id');
        $query->where('a.id = '.(int) $userId);

        // Execute the query and load the rules from the result.
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $result = $db->loadResult();
        print_r((array)$result);
```

of which, I get the output-

```
Array([0] => 2)
```

but I want it to be `Array([0] => 2, [1]=> 11)`

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I looked upon and find a similar function [here](http://docs.joomla.org/API16%3aJAccess/getGroupsByUser), using the similar query(better as expected).

Here is part of that code-

```
        $query  = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select($recursive ? 'b.id' : 'a.id');
        $query->from('#__user_usergroup_map AS map');
        $query->where('map.user_id = '.(int) $userId);
        $query->leftJoin('#__usergroups AS a ON a.id = map.group_id');

        // If we want the rules cascading up to the global asset node we need a self-join.
        if ($recursive) {
                $query->leftJoin('#__usergroups AS b ON b.lft <= a.lft AND b.rgt >= a.rgt');
        }

        // Execute the query and load the rules from the result.
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $result = $db->loadResultArray();
```

The only difference lies in the way of obtaining table information.

I would now simple use this as-

```
jimport( 'joomla.access.access' );
$groups = JAccess::getGroupsByUser(526, False); //526 is the user_id for user b
print_r($groups);
```

and this did what I want-

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 11 )
```

Thanks google.